# How do libraries such as requests have “period” functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example:

`requests.get()` is a function with a period in it. How would I make my own function ex:

```py
def foo():
    return 'bar'
```

And call said function like this:

`x.foo()`

Not like this:

`foo()`

Comment: `requests` is a package and `get` is a function in the namespace of that package. The dot is just the operator to access an *attribute* of something, it does not belong to the name.

Comment: you could either create a module (or package) and put your function in there or create a class with a static method. but why would you want do do that?

Comment: You can call a function with a period if `x` is an instance of a class where `foo()` is a function in the class. Here, `requests` is a library which contains classes and functions. So, you are able to access functions in it using `.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Python Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html):

```
class x:
    def foo():
        return 'bar'
```

Or use a `staticmethod`:

```
class x:
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        return 'bar'
```

Comment: What is the benefit of using `staticmethod`?

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice that you also have to do `import requests`. This is because `requests` is either a Python module or a Python package. You can write those yourself, if you like.

```py
# src/library.py  OR  src/library/__init__.py
# ^-module-----^      ^-package-------------^

def foo():
    return "bar"
```

```py
# src/main.py

import library  # the name of the other python file

x = library.foo()
assert x == 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you want something like that:

```
class x:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def foo(self):
         print "Hello"
```

if then you try to do, for example: b=x(), b.foo() will call foo